# Problem with reading lines from txt or with dictionary usage in Python 3.10

Tags: python, class, dictionary, readlines

For OOP learning reasons, (for now) created a dictionary class with regions and a class where you can move between regions with limited access, so for example from region 3 you are able only to go to regions 2, 4, 6, 8 or from region 10 only to region 9. Problem occured when I wanted to add description for regions. For few regions it reads wrong lines and can't find a reason.

```
(...)
class Territory(object):

    def __init__(self, **regions):
        player = Player()
        self.player = player
        regions_file = open("regiony.txt", "r")
        regions_description = regions_file.readlines()
        regions = { 
            1: {1: 2, "desc": regions_description[2]},
            2: {1: 3, "desc": regions_description[3],
                4: 1, "desc": regions_description[1]}, # prints regions_description[3] instead
            3: {1: 8, "desc": regions_description[8], # prints regions_description[4] instead
                2: 6, "desc": regions_description[6], # prints regions_description[6] instead
                3: 4, "desc": regions_description[4], # prints regions_description[8] instead
                4: 2, "desc": regions_description[2]},
            4: {2: 3, "desc": regions_description[3],
                4: 5, "desc": regions_description[5]},
            5: {1: 4, "desc": regions_description[4]}, # prints regions_description[6] instead
            6: {1: 7, "desc": regions_description[7],
                3: 3, "desc": regions_description[3]},
            7: {3: 8, "desc": regions_description[8], # prints regions_description[4] instead
                4: 6, "desc": regions_description[6]},
            8: {1: 9, "desc": regions_description[9],
                2: 7, "desc": regions_description[7],
                4: 3, "desc": regions_description[3]},
            9: {1: 10, "desc": regions_description[10],
                4: 8, "desc": regions_description[8]}, # prints regions_description[4] instead
            10: {4: 9, "desc": regions_description[9]}}
        self.__dict__.update(regions)
        regions_file.close()


class Moving(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.territory = Territory()
        self.regions = self.territory.__dict__

    def movement(self):
        region = 1
        path = 1
        POSSIBLE_PATHS = (1, 2, 3, 4, 0)
        print(region)
        print(self.regions[region]["desc"])
        while path:
            try:
                path = int(input("Which path you take? "))
                if path in POSSIBLE_PATHS:       
                    region = self.regions[region][path]
                    print(region)
                    print(self.regions[region]["desc"])
                elif path == 0:
                        break
            except:
                while path not in POSSIBLE_PATHS: 
                    path = int(input("Which path you take? "))
(...)
```

`regiony.txt` for now is just:

```
test1
test2
(...)
test9
test10
```

Tried to move `regions_file` and `regions_description` to `def movement` and use `print(regions_description[region])`, but effect was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't solve it for few hrs earlier, but the idea came just when wanted to refresh my mind while jogging :) seems like a rookie mistake

In case someone else faces this problem in the future, adding `"desc": regions_description[x]` to each row was a mistake, it should be only in rows of main keys.

```
            1: {1: 2, "desc": regions_description[1]},
            2: {1: 3, "desc": regions_description[2],
                4: 1},
            3: {1: 8, "desc": regions_description[3],
                2: 6,
                3: 4,
                4: 2},
            4: {2: 3, "desc": regions_description[4],
                4: 5},
            5: {1: 4, "desc": regions_description[5]},
            6: {1: 7, "desc": regions_description[6],
                3: 3},
            7: {3: 8, "desc": regions_description[7],
                4: 6},
            8: {1: 9, "desc": regions_description[8],
                2: 7,
                4: 3},
            9: {1: 10, "desc": regions_description[9],
                4: 8},
            10: {4: 9, "desc": regions_description[10]}}
```